# Using linux kernel 2.6.18, trying to encrypt

Tags: c, linux, encryption, linux-kernel

I just can't seem to understand how crypto api works.  I looked at examples and documentation regarding digest a ciphers, but I'm still very much confused.

in kernel space

```
...
unsigned char key[16] = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07,
        0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f }; //# used as key
struct crypto_tfm *tfm;
struct scatterlist sg;
...
static ssize_t go_encrypt_write(struct file *filp, char *buffer,
                        size_t length, loff_t *offset)
{
    osprd_info_t *d = file2osprd(filp);
    uint8_t *tmp = kmalloc(sizeof(uint8_t), GFP_ATOMIC);
    struct scatterlist sg;
    copy_from_user(tmp, buffer, length);
    tfm = crypto_alloc_tfm("aes", 0);
    crypto_cipher_setkey(tfm, key, 16);
    sg_set_buf(&sg, tmp, length);
    crypto_cipher_encrypt(tfm, &sg, &sg, length);
    memcpy(d->data, tmp, length);
    return length;
}
```

Basic idea is that I want to copy over the buffer from user space (a string) to kernel space encrypted.

Since I can't directly access user space stuff in kernel space, I have to use copy_from_user. From here I am setting up my transform to use aes algorithm. Then I set a hardcoded key of length 16. Then I set up a scatter list from the buffer from userspace. Then when I encrypt sg, at this point shouldn't 'tmp' be encrypted?

When I read later I still get the original string without encryption. What am I doing wrong?  Thank you.

Comment: `sizeof(uint8_t)` is definitely not the right length for kmalloc.

Comment: It seems like crypto_cipher_encrypt is failing, I'm not sure why.